# Slight flattening an object with GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

My entities in Java look like

```
{
    id: 123,
    name: "Some Name",
    someList: [1, 2, 3],
    data: {
        someDetail: "Whatever",
        anotherDetail: "And so on"
    }
}
```

i.e., I moved some boring stuff into an `@Embeddable Data data`. It's fine for use in Java, but I'm transferring the entities (without DTOs) via GSON and in Javascript, I'd strongly prefer a more flat structure

```
{
    id: 123,
    name: "Some Name",
    someList: [1, 2, 3],
    someDetail: "Whatever",
    anotherDetail: "And so on"
}
```

The only wanted change is treating the content of `data` as if it was in the main object directly, other parts should stay as they're. The deserialization is needed, too.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a simple data class that transform the neccessary data points to single level from an input class.
Then you can export that flat class as json.

```
class objectFlat {
    int id;
    String name;
    List<Integer> someList;
    String someDetail;
    public objectFlat(ObjectInput input) {
        this.id = input.id;
        this.name = input.name;
        this.someList = input.someList;
        this.someDetail = input.getData().someDetail;
    }

}
```